# Column/Row index in a DataGrid column

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I was hoping the following would get me column index in the cell:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rec. No." Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Path=Column.DisplayIndex}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But it didn't. Anyone can tell me what's wrong here?

I'm actually looking for the row index (need a Record No. column in my grid), but since `DataGridRow` doesn't apparently have an "index" kind of property, I tried to first do it for column index, which has got `DisplayIndex`. But even this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Binding syntax is incorrect**. Instead of `Source`, it should be `RelativeSource`:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, 
               Path=Column.DisplayIndex}"
```

---

And for second problem for getting `RowIndex`, there is no inbuilt property such as `RowIndex` on DataGridRow.

**I would suggest to have some property in underlying data class and bind to that.**

However, you can get rowIndex manually as well by having **[IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** in place.

```
public class RowIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

        return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock
     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, 
                          Converter={StaticResource RowIndexConverter}}"/>
```

Ofcourse, you need to declare instance of Converter under resources section of your XAML to use that.

Comment: Thanks. That solves half of the problem. Now do you see any way of getting row index?

Comment: There is no inbuilt property on DataGridRow. You can have index property in underlying data class or have Converter in place to manually get row index.

Comment: Updated in an answer..!!