# How to keep my items in datagrid in sequence order when item from middle is deleted WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I am loading items from database to my `DataGrid` on this way (on form load):

```
dataGridArticles.ItemsSource = null;
dataGridArticles.ItemsSource = listCurrentArticles;
```

And I got ability to add item to my datagrid list, and also I have ability to remove them by pressing DEL key <*datagrid automatically removes it from a list*>.

But When I am entering item to my list which is source to datagrid I am also setting OrdinalNumber for each item, for example when I adding new item to a list I am doing next thing:

```
article.OrdinalNumber = GetCurrentlyMaxOrdinalNumber()+1;
```

so if I'm adding items one after other, ordinals numbers will be 1,2,3,4,5... and so on, something like this (marked red) :

[image]

My stored procedure which is returning max ordinal number from articles table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ArticleGetNextCodeNumber`()
BEGIN
Select ifnull(max(OriginalArticleCode),0)
from articles;
END
```

And this is what is happening when I am adding new item to my list:
I am setting next ordinal numbers and some other attributes for new article:

```
 private void btnSaveChangesOnArticle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (newItem)
                {


                    Article newArticle = new Article();

                    newArticle.ArticleCode = txtArticleCode.Text.Trim();
                    newArticle.OriginalArticleCode = Convert.ToInt32(ArticlesController.Instance.GetNextArticleCode()) + 1; // Here I'm setting new article ordinal number

                    newArticle.Title = txtArticleTitle.Text.Trim();
                    newArticle.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text.Trim());


                    var lastInserted = ArticlesController.Instance.Save(newArticle);



                    MessageBox.Show("Operation Successful.");



                    listCurrentArticles.Add(lastInserted);

                    dataGridArticles.ItemsSource = null;
                    dataGridArticles.ItemsSource = listCurrentArticles;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am wondering right now, when user press DELETE KEY to remove some item from my datagrid,how can I reorganize my ordinal numbers, because if I add 5 items for example to my datagrid, and if user delete second item, than my order might look like this: 1 3 4 5.. insted of 1 2 3 4

So my question is guys, how can i reorganize that, when something changes to keep it sequenced all the time ( *so maybe then I dont need to keep ordinal number in database, because it is not important to me, I am using it just because of better UI look, to show to user how many items he added to that DataGrid*).

Thanks a lot,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the OrdinalNumber `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and use a converter to return the value of the `GetIndex()` method of the parent `DataGridRow` container.

You need to bind to both the parent `DataGridRow` and the `Count` property of the `Items` property of the `DataGrid` itself for the binding to get refreshed when the number of items changes, i.e. when an item is added or removed.

This should be pretty simple to implement. You create a class that implements the `IMultiValueConverter` interface:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class RowNumberConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((values[0] as DataGridRow).GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridArticles" AutoGenerateColumns="False" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:RowNumberConverter x:Key="RowNumberConverter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="#" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RowNumberConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}" />
                                <Binding Path="Items.Count" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- + the rest of your columns -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: it works nice but why do I need to include xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" to my datagrid, because I need to access class from code behind which is located there? Is it going to mess anything else, anything related to behavior of my datagrid? and because this items are populating my datagrid from database, can I somehow detect when user delete item, I know UI will take care of that it will look like item is removed, but it's still in database? So mate could I somehow catch that event which is removing item from datagrid to call my remove stored procedure to remove it at all :)

Comment: You need to include the namespace mapping for the compiler to be resolve the converter type. An no, it won't affect anything else in your DataGrid. You are simply telling the compiler in which namespace the RowNumberConverter class is defined.

Comment: should I ask new question because I want to delete item really from my database when it's removed from UI datagrid also. :)

Comment: Yes. If you have a new issue you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this related question that might solve your problem.

[Column/Row index in a DataGrid column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648873/column-row-index-in-a-datagrid-column)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to remove *OrdinalNumber* property (Since you do not need it, as you said) and use *DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate* with a converter. Here is a working example:

**MainWindow**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        listCurrentArticles = new ObservableCollection<Article>() { new Article { Text = "k" }, new Article { Text = "l" } };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Article> listCurrentArticles { get; set; }
```

**Xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HeaderConverter x:Key="headerConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding listCurrentArticles}">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="25" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource headerConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                            <Binding Path="Item" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Converter**

```
public class HeaderConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Article> list = values[0] as ObservableCollection<Article>;
        Article obj = values[1] as Article;
        int ind = list.IndexOf(obj);
        if (ind == -1)
            return "+";
        else
            return (ind + 1).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```